# Onclick/offclick? JS Timer? How to make each one work repeatedly

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am new to JS and using  so i am attempting to make this image slider work to my advantage. I want o make each thumbnail clickable to make the larger image slide into place. I was able to make this work with a CSS hover effect but i need it to work on click instead. I got it working but you can only click it once. the images don't revert back down to their original state how do i fix this? is there a timer setting so that it would revert after 1 second? or it auto resets when you click a different thumb?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lumberjack225/t7r17r92/

HTML

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").style.top = "100px";
}
function myFunction2() {
document.getElementById("demo2").style.top = "100px";
}
function myFunction3() {
document.getElementById("demo3").style.top = "100px";
}
</script>

<!-- Mobile Slider -->
<div class="mobileslider">
<div class="innermobile">
<div class="container3">
<span  onclick="myFunction()" href="#">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460899960812-f6ee1ecaf117?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1400" width="75px" height="75px">
    <img id="demo" class="big2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460899960812-f6ee1ecaf117?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1400" width="300px">
</span>

<span onclick="myFunction2()" href="#">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400355256-e87506dcec4f?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1400" width="75px" height="75px">
    <img id="demo2" class="big2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460400355256-e87506dcec4f?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1400" width="300px">
</span>

<span onclick="myFunction3()" href="#">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453230806017-56d81464b6c5?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1400" width="75px" height="75px">
    <img id="demo3" class="big2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453230806017-56d81464b6c5?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1400" width="300px">
</span>
<a href="#">
  <center>  <img class="big2 featuredm" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1456318019777-ccdc4d5b2396?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1400" width="300px"></center>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container3 {
position: relative;
height: 297px;
width: 95%;
overflow: hidden;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container3 a {
float: left;
margin-top: 9px;
margin-right: 9px;
margin-left: 9px;
margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.container3 span {
float: left;
margin-top: 9px;
margin-right: 9px;
margin-left: 9px;
margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.container2 {
position: relative;
height: 660px;
width: 960px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.container2 a {
float: left;
margin: 20px;
}

.big {
position: absolute;
top: 260px;
left: 20px;
}

.big2 {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 0px;
}
.big {
position: absolute;
top: 900px;
left: 20px;

-webkit-transition: top .5s ease;
-moz-transition: top .5s ease;
-o-transition: top .5s ease;
-ms-transition: top .5s ease;
transition: top .5s ease;
}
.big2 {
position: absolute;
top: 900px;
-webkit-transition: top .5s ease;
-moz-transition: top .5s ease;
-o-transition: top .5s ease;
-ms-transition: top .5s ease;
transition: top .5s ease;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.featured {
top: 260px;
left: 20px;
z-index: -3;
}

.featuredm {
top: 100px;
left: 0px;
z-index: -3;
}

a:hover .thumb {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

a:hover .big {
top: 260px;
}

span:hover .thumb {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }

.featured2 {
top: 260px;
left: 20px;
z-index: -3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset the position, we never change the individual top position for the .big2 images. Instead, lets create a new class that we apply to the selected image.

css:

```
.selected {
  top: 100px;
}
```

Whenever we click a thumb. We will add or remove this class from the .big2 images to move them up and down. Then we add it to the image corresponding to the clicked thumb.

javascript:

We grab all elements with the .thumb class and store them in an array called thumbs, we do the same with the .big2 and store them in bigs.

```
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb');
var bigs = document.querySelectorAll('.big2');
```

We now have two lists with the same order, eg: thumbs[thumb0,thumb1,thumb2], bigs[big0,big1,big2]. Lets add some click events to our thumbs. We loop through the thumb list. For every item in the list, we add a click event listener.
Inside this listener function, we run our function returnAll(), which removes the .selected class from all items in the bigs list. We then add the selected class to the big at the same position in the list as the thumb we just clicked.

```
for (i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        thumbs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            returnAll();
            bigs[i].classList.add("selected")
        });
})(i);
}

function returnAll(){
    for (i = 0; i < bigs.length; i++) {
        bigs[i].classList.remove("selected");
  }
}
```

Here is your fiddle, updated with the above code:
https://jsfiddle.net/t7r17r92/3/

Notice that I moved all javascript into a "file" of its own, for clarity.

Good luck!